# Repeated-measures ANCOVA using aov AND Error function

Tags: r, anova, covariance

I have looked into other answers found on SE but still do not feel that my case matches other posters' data. I would like to perform a RM-ANCOVA on the following data:

```
df<-read.csv(header=T, text="
ID, Group, Hemi, total, wealth
100, 0, 0, 39, 1.99
100, 0, 1, 44, 1.99
101, 0, 0, 38, 2.01
101, 0, 1, 23, 2.01
200, 1, 0, 33, 80.1
200, 1, 1, 23, 80.1
202, 1, 0, 18, 12.1
202, 1, 1, 28, 12.1")
#hemi=0 for left, hemi=1 for right
```

The covariate in this data is the `wealth`, with the between-subjects effect `Group` and repeated effect `hemi`. `total` is the response.

I tried following the example here but am not sure if this is the right approach given what I want as I am relatively new to using R.

```
#Fitting the ANCOVA 
brain.out<-aov(total~group+hemi+Error(ID)+wealth, data=df)
```

My questions are: (1) Is this the correct syntax for what I am trying to model? (2) How do I perform an ANCOVA with `Error` in the `aov` ? I know `Anova::car` provides ANCOVA but does not allow `Error` in the `aov` statement

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.